# Error when selecting a cell in UITableView to open a UIAlertController

Tags: swift, uitableview, ios9, uisearchcontroller

I have a UITableView with a UISearchController. When I don't search for anything and select a cell the UIAlertController open just fine, but when I search for a cell and select it, it gives me an error.

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x15481000>  on <Where.ViewController: 0x15344400> which is already presenting (null)
```

I don't know why this error/warning appears.

Here is my didSelectRowAtIndexPath and updateSearchResultsForSearchController delegates:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


        if(self.resultSearchController.active)
        {
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

            let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as UITableViewCell

            print(currentCell.detailTextLabel!.text)

            AlertMessage((currentCell.textLabel?.text)!, Number: (currentCell.detailTextLabel?.text!)!)

        }
        else
        {
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

            let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as UITableViewCell

            print(currentCell.detailTextLabel!.text)

            AlertMessage((currentCell.textLabel?.text)!, Number: (currentCell.detailTextLabel?.text!)!)


        }

    }

    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

        PersonFilterArr.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

        let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.name CONTAINS [c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
        let array = (self.PersonArr as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
        PersonFilterArr = array as! [Person]

        self.ContactsTableView.reloadData()

    }
```

And here is my UIAlerController which should open when a cell is selected, but only work if you dont search for a cell. Hope you guys can help thank you.

```
 func AlertMessage(Name: String, Number: String)
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Send Message", message: "Tell " + Name +  " where you are", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { action in
            print("Yes")
            let messageVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()

            messageVC.body = self.StreetName + " " + self.LocalityPostal + " " + self.AdministrativeArea + " " + self.Country;
            messageVC.recipients = [Number]
            messageVC.messageComposeDelegate = self;

            self.presentViewController(messageVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { action in
            print("No")
            })

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```